# How can we make ejabberd server use existing users data, instead of creating a new database for roster?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Suppose a website has already registered users, and has a way for them to add and remove friend from their own friendlist through website.

Now, I want to use ejabberd xmpp server for getting presence information in real-time, but I don't want to have xmpp server to create new database for roster.
Is there any way to configure ejabberd to avoid data duplication on both ejabberd server and website server?

Answer (score 4):

1. If you don't want to write a custom ejabberd module, you can configure ejabberd to load rosters from a SQL database.   If all your rosters modifications are done by your webapp,  then from ejabberd point of view the DB is "read only", and you could write a SQL view that has the schema expected by ejabberd but uses the data tables you already have.
   See table definitions https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/odbc/mysql.sql  , you need "rosterusers" and "rostergroups" table. Note that this approach has some limitations.  Changes in roster won't be seen immediately by connected users unless your application informs ejabberd about that, so ejabberd can inform the clients.  For this you probably need to write custom code anyway, and learn about roster push http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#roster
2. Or you can write your own custom module to access your roster data.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ejabberd use Mnesia database for Users and Roster etc.
You can configure Ejabberd with external database like SQL SERVER, MySQL, Postgress etc.

You have to configure the ejabberd to use external database (ex: odbc) instead of internal database.

Please see the below to configure Ejabberd with MySQL:
http://iohq.net/index.php?title=Building_an_Ejabberd_Server_with_MySql

After that right a sql script to transfer your existing users in "users" and "rosteruser" table with proper subscription value. Changes in roster done directly in "rosteruser" won't be seen immediately by connected users. To resolve this you can get the friend request confirmation event from application logic (php/asp.net/java) and than add roster through XMPP client. Using this process all roster updation events will be reflected on all connected.

Comment: what if the MySQL schema is different?